# What does the second property in Halmos definition of continuation mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

Halmos defines in his book "Naive Set Theory" that a well-ordered set A is a continuation of a well-ordered set B if

1. B is a subset of A
2. B is an initial segmemt of A
3. the ordering of the elememts in B is the same as the ordering in A.

I do not understand what he means with the second property.
Is it that B is an initial segment of some element in A?

Comment: See [Initial segment](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Initial_Segment)

Comment: Ok, thx. But am i correct then to infer that if the definition of an initial segment is that of the site you posted, then a set A that is an initial segment of an well-ordered set X can not be a continuation of itself?

Comment: i think it would not satusfy the second condition, i think if B is an initial segment of B then B is an initial segment determined by some elememt of B. Let b be that element, then B will not contain b which is a contradiction. Is this reasoning wrong?

Comment: You are correct. By that definition, an initial segment of $A$ must be a proper subset of $A$.

Comment: See Halmos, page 56, for the definition of *initial segment* determined by an element $a$ of $A$. In the case above, we have to read that there is some $a \in A$ such that $B$ is the initial segment determined by $a$.

Comment: But then i am confused by something Halmos writes in his book. He says:  "If C is an arbitrary collection of initial segments of a well-ordered set, then C is a chain with respect tocontinuation; this means that C is a collectionof well-ordered sets with the property that of any two distinct members of the collection one is a continuation of the other."

Comment: Does he mean with  "chain" in this context only the property that he points out or is it that the "continuation-order" satisfies all three properties of a partial order? The latter one would imply that a set of that collection is an initial segment of itself.

Comment: sorry, i meant an element of the collection not a set

Comment: He must mean a strict partial order.

Comment: @Joe Yep, that might be the case. Is a bit surprising because i dont remember  he mentioned specifically the term strict partial order and the irreflexive property. Thx to all who contributed!